# OpenBSD disk devices prefixes

Tags: partition, openbsd, dev

Under OpenBSD, /dev/rsd0a means:

- **r**aw access
- to the first, or root, slice (**a**)
- of the first (**0**) SCSI (**sd**) disk

**r** says that the device is accessed in raw, character mode instead of the standard block access. Are there other known special prefixes like this one, or is it the only one?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. You could always have tried `ls /dev/*sd0a` to see what other device nodes existed. What other modes would you expect to have available?

Comment: None; I'm only studying OpenBSD, between assigned tasks, and haven't installed it yet, trying to understand it a bit before taking the plunge. Besides, there could be some that only arise with some configurations, and that wouldn't show on mine.

Comment: The man pages are all online: http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man4/sd.4

Comment: I studied them too, but I wanted to ask, in the case there was some prefixes I missed or poorly documented, despite the cared documentation OpenBSD is renowned for.